# QCreator Encoding Result

Tags: encoding, qt-creator

I'm using QCreator. I can't display characters of a non-English language. I tried to change the encoding using `Edit -> Select encoding -> ..`, but I think I chose something different by mistake; and after some reloading/saving, I now see strange characters on the screen and can't see my code. Do I have a chance to save my work? I don't want to lose any data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the file in an application that has heuristics that autodetect the encoding. Firefox, for example (try a few different browsers.) If it's successful, you can then copy&paste the text to a new file.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but unfortunately I can't recover it.Here is a screenshot from Firefox, with utf-8 encoding.
[link](http://images.imagelinky.com/1352137252.PNG)